# Libgdx falling circles

Tags: java, libgdx, geometry

I am working on a libgdx game and am having a certain problem. I am trying to constantly generate random coordinates (above the screen) and for each coordinate, draw a circle. Then add to their y-coordinates so they will have a falling effect. Once a circle is off the screen, it will be deleted.

Here I create 2D list. It contains arrays of random coordinates in the screen.

```
List<List<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

public void makePoints() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        List<Integer> lst1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int randX = randInt(10,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-10);
        int randY = randInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-10);
        lst1.add(randX);
        lst1.add(randY);
        lst.add(lst1);
    }
}
```

Once prior to the game loop, I call the function

Then inside the game loop, I do this. (Keep in mind this is run over and over)

```
//Draw a circle for each coordinate in the arraylist
    for (int i=0; i<lst.size();i++){
        shapeRenderer.circle((lst.get(i)).get(0), (lst.get(i)).get(1), 30);
    }

    //Add 1 to the y value of each coordinate
    for (int i=0; i<lst.size();i++){
        lst.get(i).set(1, i + 1);
    }
```

Currently, it draws 10 circles and drops them extremely fast.
I need to be able to constantly generate points and slow down the dropping.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a while loop, which runs while the game is still alive. Remove your for i less than 10 loop and implement the while loop and it will continue to create balls for lifetime of the thread. As for slowing down the creation of the balls - call the thread.sleep() function and implement a similar method to this:

```
public void run()
{
        while (alive)
        {
            createNewCircle();
            updateGame();
            repaint();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

For more information on programming with threads - Check [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/) out

Comment: I would keep your makePoints method as it is, but remove the for loop from it. Because this will continue to be called inside the while(alive) loop so you don't need to create 10 balls every time it updates. This will create a new ball every 1/10th of a second as it is (change the Thread.sleep() value to slow it down)

Comment: During your game loop. Check out my updated code. The run() method should be implemented inside your Game (thread) class

Comment: Yep. And then you can create a listener or some event to handle the game finishing and set the alive variable to false. This will stop the thread from running